# Clone div and delete div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don't understand why all Functions are not working. Normally if you click on the button "+ Loc de munca" needs to appear input and then if you click further on the "+ Loc de munca" need to clone all input. Also if you click on the "Sterge" need everything to delete. Here is the code:

```js
var itm = document.getElementById("myList4").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

function appearafter2() {
  document.getElementById("buttonappear2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("hinzufuegen2").style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction2() {
  var itm = document.getElementById("myList4").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("myList3").appendChild(cln);
}

function deleteFunction2() {
  var list3 = document.getElementById("myList3");
  var divs = Array.from(list3.getElementsByTagName("div"));

  // If the number of divs is 4, it means we're removing the last
  // cloned div, hide the delete button.
  if (divs.length === 4) {
    document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none";
  }

  var lastDivToDelete2 = divs[divs.length - 1];

  list3.removeChild(lastDivToDelete2);
}

function allFunction2() {
  myFunction2();
  appearafter2();
}
```

```css
#button2 {
  display: none;
}

#buttonappear2 {
  display: none;
}

.input-data2 {
  width: 49%;
}
.label-data2 {
  width: 50%;
}
#myList3 {
  display: none;
}
#label-job-input-inline {
  display: inlin-block;
}
.label-job-input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hinzufuegen2" onclick="allFunction2()">
  + Loc de munca
</div>
<div id="myList3">
  <div id="button2" onclick="deleteFunction2()">Șterge</div>
  <div id="myList4">
    <div id="addingNewJob">
      <label class="label-job-input" for="job-input-1">Numele firmei</label>
      <select size="1" type="text" id="job-input-1" /><option value="scoala_generala">școala generală</option>
  <option value="scoala">școală profesională</option>
  <option value="lic">liceu</option>
  <option value="fac">facultate</option></select>
      <label class="label-job-input" for="job-input-2">Postul ocupat
      </label>
      <input size="1" type="text" id="job-input-3" /><br />
      <label class="label-data2" for="job-input-3">din data</label><label class="label-data2" for="job-input-4">până la data</label><br />
      <input type="number" style="width: 48%" />
      <input type="number" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 6px" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div onclick="allFunction2()" id="buttonappear2">
  + Loc de munca
</div>
```

Hello, I don't understand why all Functions are not working. Normally if you click on the button "+ Loc de munca" needs to appear input and then if you click further on the "+ Loc de munca" need to clone all input. Also if you click on the "Sterge" need everything to delete. Here is the code:

Answer (score 0):

Updated the answer, check if this is what you are trying to achieve.

```js
function myFunction2() {
            var cln = '<div class="list-item">'+
            '<div id="addingNewJob">'+
            '<label class="label-job-input" for="job-input-1">Numele firmei</label>'+
            '<select size="1" type="text" id="job-input-1" /></div>';
          
            document.getElementById("myList3").innerHTML+=cln;      
            document.getElementById("buttonappear2").classList.remove('hide');          
            document.getElementById("button2").classList.remove('hide');
            document.getElementById("hinzufuegen2").classList.add('hide');        
        }

        function deleteFunction2() {
            var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".list-item"));      
            if(divs.length>0){
                var lastDivToDelete2 = divs[divs.length - 1];
                document.getElementById("myList3").removeChild(lastDivToDelete2);
            }
            if(divs.length==1){
                document.getElementById("buttonappear2").classList.add('hide');         
            document.getElementById("button2").classList.add('hide');
            document.getElementById("hinzufuegen2").classList.remove('hide');
            }
        }
```

```css
.hide{
      display: none;
    }
    .input-data2 {
      width: 49%;
    }
    .label-data2 {
      width: 50%;
    }   
    #label-job-input-inline {
      display: inlin-block;
    }
    .label-job-input {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="hinzufuegen2" onclick="myFunction2()">+ Loc de munca</div>
    <div id="myList3">
        <div id="button2" class="hide" onclick="deleteFunction2()">Șterge</div>
    </div>
    școala generală școală profesională liceu facultate
    <label class="label-job-input" for="job-input-2">Postul ocupat</label>
    <form>
        <input size="1" type="text" id="job-input-3" />
        <br />
        <label class="label-data2" for="job-input-3">din data</label>
        <label class="label-data2" for="job-input-4">până la data</label>
        <br />
        <input type="number" style="width: 48%;" />
        <input type="number" style="width: 50%; margin-left: 6px;" />
    </form>
    <div onclick="myFunction2()" class="hide" id="buttonappear2">+ Loc de munca</div>
```

Comment: First of all, I thank you a lot. The Problem is that I wanted if I click on "Sterge" at least every input disappears and in the end only "+ Loc de munca" remains.

Comment: And if I click on the "+ Loc de munca" I need that all input first only one time to appear. Then only if you click further on the "+ Loc de munca" to clone all input for one time more. I need in the end to can delete all input and only the div "+ Loc de munca". Thank you.

Comment: @Gheorghe-RobertCandea . updated the answer, check if this is what you want